# docker not able to locate the file

Tags: docker

I am getting error while trying execute below command

```
 docker run --rm -v /home/docker:/build ethereum/solc:stable /build/TransactionFee.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o /build
```

Error is

> "/Users/amidala/projects/TransactionFee.sol" is not found.

The file is already exists:

```
amidalas-MacBook-Pro:projects amidala$ ls -ltr build/ docker/ TransactionFee.sol
-rwxr-xr-x  1 amidala  staff  730 Dec 10 23:46 TransactionFee.sol

docker/:

build/:
amidalas-MacBook-Pro:projects amidala$ docker run --rm -v /Users/amidala/projects/docker:/Users/amidala/projects/build ethereum/solc:stable /Users/amidala/projects/TransactionFee.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o /Users/amidala/projects/build
"/Users/amidala/projects/TransactionFee.sol" is not found.
amidalas-MacBook-Pro:projects amidala$
```

As you can see the file exists

[image]

**/users** already shared

[image]

Am I missing anything?

I am following the article [Intro to Blockchain](https://dzone.com/articles/intro-to-blockchain-with-ethereum-web3j-and-spring)

Comment: Can you do a PWD from the current directory and ls -R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you command:

```
docker run --rm \
    -v /User/amidala/projects/docker:/Users/amidala/projects/build \
    etherun/solc:stable \
    /User/amidala/projects/TransactionFee.sol \
    --bin --abi --optimize -o /Users/amidala/projects/build
```

You telling docker to mount your local folder `/User/amidala/projects/docker` to containers folder `/Users/amidala/projects/build` *(That's the `-v` argument)*. So in the folder `/Users/amidala/projects` inside the container is only the docker folder and nothing more. No TransactionFee.sol file.

You probably want to mount `/User/amidala/projects` folder to containers `/User/amidala/projects`. So the whole `projects` folder is avabile for container.

```
docker run --rm \
    -v /User/amidala/projects:/User/amidala/projects \
    etherun/solc:stable \
    /User/amidala/projects/TransactionFee.sol \
    --bin --abi --optimize -o /Users/amidala/projects/build
```

---

PS: Using the same folder structure in container as io the host is good for simplicity, but not good for being sure to which folder you are referring.

There whole docker docs page about volumes and mounting: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Just for FYI, I have pasted as text also, which I have formatted as text.

Comment: @secretsuperstar sorry, i somehow missed that. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Michal Hošna's answer is accurate. But I would keep the container folder structure as is. Try running:

```
docker run --rm -v /Users/amidala/projects/docker:/build ethereum/solc:stable /build/TransactionFee.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o /build
```

Maybe the container is expecting things to happen within the build folder and you might get other errors when running your build.